# common lisp bindings for ZeroMQ

Tags: common-lisp, zeromq

I am new to Lisp and am trying to learn. In particular, I am trying to use the ZeroMQ library to make a distributed system. 
**This is my exploratory code**

```
;;hwserver.lisp
(defun main()
  ;; prepare contexts
  (zmq:with-context (context)
    (zmq:with-socket (socket context zmq:rep)
      (zmq:bind socket "tcp://*5555")

      (loop
     (let ((request (make-instance 'zmq:msg)))

       ;; wait for next request from client
       (zmq:recv socket request)
       (print "received request: [~A]~%"
            (zmq:msg-data-as-string request))

       ;;do some work
       (sleep 1)

       ;;send reply back to client
       (let ((reply (make-instance 'zmq:msg :data "Hello World")))
         (zmq:send socket reply))))))
  (sb-ext:exit))
```

**In the REPL, I run the following commands**

```
(ql:quickload "zeromq")
(load "hwserver.lisp")
```

**And then I get the following warning.**

```
; 
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: ZEROMQ:REP
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined variable:
;     ZEROMQ:REP
;   caught 1 WARNING condition
```

Though zmq:rep is exported from the [zeromq package](http://repo.or.cz/cl-zmq.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/src/package.lisp).

And if I ignore the warning try to run `(main)`, I get the **following error**

```
The variable ZEROMQ:REP is unbound.
   [Condition of type UNBOUND-VARIABLE]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "repl-thread" RUNNING {10039B0003}>)

Backtrace:
  ;; backtrace omitted for being uninteresting here
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

> (zmq:with-socket (socket context zmq:rep)

creates this error

> The variable ZEROMQ:REP is unbound.

Means: it is a variable and it has no value. It does not matter if the symbol is exported or not.

To me it looks like the code expects a keyword symbol `:rep` as a socket type descriptor instead of your `zmq:rep`.

Another case of a bad macro not checking the types it expects.